# Defined equality does not show in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, replacement

I have some function definitions that ultimately define an equality through `Solve` and `Replace`:

```
Curve[p_] := w1*x^p + w2*y^p; (* some function with parameters *)
ComputeWeights[p1_, p2_, p_] := (* compute w1 and w2 through Solve *)
  Solve[w1 == 1 - w2 && 
     w1*p1[[1]]^p + w2*p1[[2]]^p == w1*p2[[1]]^p + w2*p2[[2]]^p, {w1, 
     w2}][[1]];
MyCurve[p1_, p2_, p_] := Curve[p] /. ComputeWeights[p1, p2, p];
MyConstant[p1_, p2_, p_] := 
  MyCurve[p1, p2, p] /. {x -> p1[[1]], y -> p1[[2]]};
MyEquality[p1_, p2_, p_] := 
  MyCurve[p1, p2, p] == MyConstant[p1, p2, p];
```

Now, I can use the defined equality:

```
t1 = {0.2, 0.5}; t2 = {0.6, 0.3}; MyEquality[t1, t2, 10]
```

which correctly outputs

```
0.138326 x^10 + 0.861674 y^10 == 0.000841493
```

If I try to graph this with a `ContourPlot`, it works fine:

```
(* ok *) ContourPlot[0.138326 x^10 + 0.861674 y^10 == 0.000841493, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

However, if I embed the MyEquality function in `ContourPlot` (which is the reason why I defined it in the first place) it no longer works (I see an empty square, but no curve):

```
(* ko *) ContourPlot[MyEquality[t1, t2, 10], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Strangely enough, it works if I use a function for the lhs of the equality:

```
(* ok *) ContourPlot[MyCurve[t1, t2, 10] == 0.000841493, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

but not if I use a function for the rhs:

```
(* ko *) ContourPlot[0.138326 x^10 + 0.861674 y^10 == MyConstant[t1, t2, 10], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

There must be something profound I don't understand about replacements and equalities (and possibly function definitions) in Mathematica. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the first argument of `ContourPlot` with [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html):

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@MyEquality[t1, t2, 10], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Notes:**

`ContourPlot` (and all `*Plot` functions) have the `Attribute` [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), that is, *all arguments are maintained in an **unevaluated form**.*

So, in a simpler example,

```
eqn = Cos[x] == Cos[y]; 
ContourPlot[eqn, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

does not produce anything because `ContourPlot` sees `eqn` not `Cos[x] == Cos[y]`. Forcing evaluation of `eqn` by wrapping it with `Evaluate`,

```
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

works as if we used

```
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] == Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! But what is it that prevents the resulting expression to be evaluated, i.e., why do I have to force evaluation?

Comment: @Maiaux, `ContourPlot` (and all `*Plot` functions) have the  `Attribute` `HoldAll` ( that is, _all arguments to a function are maintained in an unevaluated form_.) So, in a simpler example, `eqn = Cos[x] == Cos[y];
ContourPlot[eqn, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]` does not produce anything because `ContourPlot` sees `eqn`  not `Cos[x] == Cos[y]`. Forcing evaluation of `eqn` by wrapping it with `Evaluate`, (`ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]`) works as if we used `ContourPlot[Cos[x] == Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: ... See also [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks @kglr. However I now wonder why my third example works (and the last one doesn’t), even without forcing evaluation. After all, they both have some parts that need to be evaluated...

Comment: @Maiaux, it is puzzling. I don't know the answer otomh. Maybe, if you have patience,  `Trace[ContourPlot[...]]` with the two inputs might reveal something about the difference.